# Azure Git Deploy Doesn't Include More Recent Commits

Tags: asp.net, git, azure, deployment, azure-deployment

I am deploying a .net application to Azure via a git deployment. However when I launch the deployment I can see it spinning on the website and eventually complete, however it has an older commit message listed and not the most recent commits. I also confirmed in /site/deployments/ that it is using an older commit ID. What would possibly cause the deploy to appear as thought it works but essentially ignore a bunch of commits after a certain point? I also confirmed in the code that it isn't getting updated.

It looks like it is just taking the commit on top (the one deployed a few weeks back) and updating the date of it to be today.

UPDATE: I will also say that this branch was initially an autodeploy and it was failing for permissions for some reason. I have a bunch of instances that have a similar code base and set up and all of them work. Not sure if the fact it was an autodeploy at first is making a difference but why would pushing directly to the remote's master look like it is working but not include updates?

UPDATE 2:
Here are photos of the progression: There is definitely commits after the one it keeps reusing that I cherry-picked from other branches.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested with local git deployment to Azure and nothing went wrong. Have the changes been committed to the branch you pushed to Azure?

Comment: Yes they have, there is a few commits since. I merged some changes in and then also a couple of commits that are just adding a space just to force another commit so I could deploy again.